# How to parse JSON(JAVA)

Tags: java, json

Как спрасить JSON в таком формате?:

```
{"name":"Afghanistan","stationcount":211},
{"name":"Albania","stationcount":25}
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Это не JSON. Во всяком случае, не валидный.

Comment: Возможно, дубликат: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)